# How to subclass UITableViewController properly in UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I am a beginner in Objective C.
I have been searching four hours, but I cannot find a single useful (for me) answer on this.

I have a TableView, but I need a title bar with it. after searching on how to do this, I found out that I have to subclass the `UITableView` in a `UINavigationController`.

note that I do not want to make a whole new app with this TableView, I want this to be part of a larger app I am working on.

since I am a beginner, I do not know how to do this, and after trying for hours i decided to post this question.

Does anybody have a tutorial, clear step-by-step description or anything like that, which clearly describes how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of the table view controller, then set it as the root view controller of the navigation controller.

```
TheTableViewController *viewController = [[TheTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
//present navigationController - [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];

...

//TheTableViewController.m
self.title = @"title";
```

Comment: This works when I create a whole new app. problem is, I want this TableView to be part of a larger app. When try to do this in an existing project, this only gives me a black screen with a title bar on top of it. when I try to set a title, it doesn't even appear in the titlebar when I start the application. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To create a bar with title , you need a `UINavigationController` that will controls the `UIViewController` each viewController of these has property called `title`. This title will appear in the top bar of navigation. so do some thing like this:

```
UITableViewController *tableVC = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableVC.title = @"myTable";
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableVC];
```

You can set the `nav` as root view controller in the DidLaunch function in `appDelegate`

Comment: sames thing as the answer below. this works when I create a whole new app with this code, but I need to put a TableViewController with titlebar in an existing app. when I use this code In my existing app, all it gives me is a black screen with a title bar on top of it. any ideas what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboards? If so, maybe this will help you:

http://kurrytran.blogspot.de/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-uitableview-tutorial.html

Happy coding, nobi